# Regex only match inside quote

Tags: regex, http

*question resolved, see the comments.

https://regex101.com/r/eXFf3v/1

I have to match inside the "AAA","BBB" quote. This is the regex I have

```
[" 3 METRE GREY4S043G 452.2288.6700EACH 83.00%30","tal20.00%0.00%Others452.220.000.0090.440.000.0","rices are shown in £452.220.0090.44"]
```

The regex I've attempt
`(?<=").*?(?=(?:\"+))`
`.{6,}(?=(?:\"))`

but the result is not what I looking for, the answer
I want to quote only  `3 METRE GREY4S043G 452.2288.6700EACH 83.00%30` and `tal20.00%0.00%Others452.220.000.0090.440.000.0` and `rices are shown in £452.220.0090.44` it also match `,` The question is not duplicate since no one asking do not match `,`. Please help. Do Not waste time complain my question instead.

[image]

Comment: So you want to match all text inside double quotes?

Comment: double quote exclude ","

Comment: So `"([^"]+)"` maybe? Assuming you only don't want to match the comma outside the quotes, since they are your elements delimiter in what seems to be an array format. Also: *"Do Not waste time complain my question instead...."* >> What??

Comment: @anubhava That also seems to match the commas.

Comment: guys I get more `(?<=(?:,)").*?(?=\"(?:,))` but not best ans yet

Comment: @NoizyZ: You may use: `(?<=")[^",]+(?=")`

Comment: final ans `(?<=(?:\[|,)").*?(?=\")`

Comment: another version `(?<=(?:\[|\,)").*?(?="(?:\]|\,))`

Comment: No need to complicate `(?<=")[^",]+(?=")` is good enough. See demo: https://regex101.com/r/eXFf3v/3

Comment: damn hell, you guys are amazing.

Comment: Why not parse the JSON file first? It's going to be a ton more reliable than any rgular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\")(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.% £]+)(?=\")
```

Comment: Would be useful if you could add some explanation about why you think this will work.